# TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'test'

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(512, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics='accuracy')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, test=(x_test, y_test), validation=(x_val, y_val), epochs=50)
```

Here's the error:

```
TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'test'
```

When I remove test, I get the same error with validation, if I remove both I get this error:

```
TypeError: fit() got multiple values for argument 'epochs'
```

Im trying to have the LSTM run with train, test and validation set.

Comment: have you checked the documentation for the TF version you're using?

Answer (score 3):

You don't pass test datasets to `fit()`, you use the validations sets during fitting and the test sets when you evaluate the trained model by calling `model.evaluate`:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=50)
```

for evaluating:

```
results = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size= #add your batch size here)
```

refer to: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate